# Composer Update Openshift

Tags: symfony, composer-php, openshift

I have a symfony application on openshift. I added the FOSUserBundle via composer to the project.
Now I need to update the composer to make it work.
My problem is:
When I connect via ssh and go to `cd app-root/runtime/repo/php/` then I try the command `composer update` I got the error:

```
php composer.phar update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Connection to xxx-yyy.rhcloud.com closed by remote host.
Connection to xxx-yyy.rhcloud.com closed.
```

The gear does not restart while processing this.
My questions is:
How can I update the composer without closing the connection?

Comment: It is possible, that the connection is closed when the gear restarts due to lack of memory. I recommend checking whether there are no memory issues as described here: https://developers.openshift.com/en/troubleshooting-faq.html#_why_is_my_application_restarting_automatically_or_having_memory_issues

Comment: no I've checked, the does not restart.

Comment: How exactly did you check the gear does not restart? When I tried this with an empty app based on the Symfony 2.3.6 Quickstart, on a small gear, it seems to be restarting due to memory issues. The same tested on a medium sized gear seems to complete the composer update just fine. I can only recommend testing this on a larger gear size...